# gcloud compute disks create with name persistent-disk-1

Tags: gcloud

I'm creating a disk based on snapshot using a command:

```
gcloud compute disks create my-disk --source-snapshot=my-snap --size=5000gb --type=pd-standard --zone=us-central1-f
```

then I attach it using:

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk my-inst --disk=my-disk --zone=us-central1-f
```

when I look at the `disks` under `compute engine` I can see the disk with the name `my-disk` and attached to the right instance (also when I check at the instance I can see that it has a disk name `my-disk`).

the problem is when I run the command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe my-inst --zone=us-central1-f --format='value(disks.deviceName)'
```

the output is :

```
my-inst;persistent-disk-1
```

where `persistent-disk-1` came from?
where is the disk `my-disk`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get more information from:

```
gcloud compute instances describe instance-2 --format='text(disks)'
```

Check if the sources correspond to the deviceNames.

Answer (score 0):

Device name and the disk name are different. Check out the help for "disks.deviceName" on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/attachDisk). The suggestion from someone else to run the same command with --format='text(disks)' is good. Also if you run this:

$ gcloud compute instances describe my-inst --zone=us-central1-f --format='value(disks.source)'

You should see a value that ends with 'zones/us-central1-f/disks/my-disk'.